# You're a donkey vs. You're donkey?

Tags: indefinite-article

**You're a donkey** vs. **You're donkey**

I know its an insult to say this sentence to someone but I would like to learn the grammar of indefinite articles. Which sentence is correct? and Why? 
If they both are correct, Is there a difference in meaning?

Should I use the indefinite (*a*) because the word *donkey* is a noun? Or should I not use it because I'm describing someone and I'm using the word *donkey* as an adjective?

Comment: An adjective meaning what?

Comment: In my native language, it means: "not smart".

Comment: Did you check a dictionary that showed that donkey could be used as an adjective in English? A quick survey of the online dictionaries suggests the adjective is restricted to a technical use in machinery (and means auxiliary not stupid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word donkey is a noun in this context, so the indefinite article should be included. That how these kind of statements work:

> - You're a donkey.
> - You're an idiot.
> - You're a buffoon.
> - You're a fool.

However, as you mention in your question, we omit the article when we use an adjective:

> - You're stupid.
> - You're silly.
> - You're foolish.
> - You're strange.

However, these don't work, and would be regarded as unnatural or incorrect:

> - <strike>You're donkey.</strike>
> - <strike>You're fool.</strike>

although, interestingly enough, we can skip the indefinite article if we omit the verb *are*, and turn it into an exclamation:

> - You idiot!
> - You fool!

Answer (score -1):

The indefinite article a has to be used as donkey is a noun.

Comment: This is not correct, or at least not accurate enough.  "You're the man!" for example, uses *the*, not *a*, and there are times when you can omit the article, for example the movie title, "I Am Wrath"

Comment: My answer was based on this specific words only. I didn't generalize it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but when you make a blanket statement like "has to" or "must" it can be easily misinterpreted and misapplied by English learners.  A good answer will explain the context and any limitations, and give alternatives and examples.  See J.R.'s answer above as a model.